# Open Port 3306 via SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, port, telnet, remote-access

I am trying to access a Remote MySQL database from a GoDaddy VPS. I have enabled remote access on my server but I need to open the 3306 port on GoDaddy's VPS. I was told by their suppor I would need to do this via SSH but they were not able to help me any further than that. I have successfully connected to my server via SSH. I have run the following command:

```
telnet myserver.com 3306
```

When I rund that command I get the following message, `SHost is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serverConnection closed by foreign host`.

How do I open the port to allow me to connect to a Remote MySQL database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use port forwarding.

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 myserver.com
```

(I assume you normally ssh to your server by running `ssh myserver.com`.)

Then, while that connection is active, connect to the database on localhost instead of myserver.com (e.g. test using `telnet localhost 3306`).

More details in the [ssh manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1).